# Trouble updating Eclipse plugins

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, mylyn

I just installed some extra repos and now I'm trying to Check for Updates but I keep getting an error that I can't seem to get past and can find nothing about it in the google.

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: EGit Mylyn 1.3.0.201202151440-r (org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group 1.3.0.201202151440-r)
Missing requirement: EGit Mylyn 1.3.0.201202151440-r (org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group 1.3.0.201202151440-r) requires 'org.eclipse.mylyn.team_feature.feature.group 3.5.0' but it could not be found
```

I'm at a bit of a loss here.  Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: More details are needed. It's telling you that it can't install something you've asked it to install because there is a prerequisite that can't be found in any of the repositories. But providing more help will require more information, such as which Eclipse package and version you have, what repo(s) you've added, what feature you selected to install, etc.

Comment: It's Eclipse 3.6.2 and it's attempting to update several things.

Android Configurator for M2E, Android DDMS, Android Development Tools, Android Hierarchy Viewer, Android Traceview, codeBeamer Eclipse Studio with Mylyn, Eclipse EGit, Eclipse JGit, EGit Mylyn, Mercurial Eclipse, Windows Binaries for Mercurial.  I just installed the Barnes and Noble Nook repo earlier and had to install those packages.  I installed some extra Google APIs while I was at it and that brought me to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a Mylyn feature. Make sure you have the [Mylyn update site](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/downloads/) in your list of software update sites and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with Mylyn in the past that could only be solved by **first uninstalling** all Mylyn plugins, then updating the remaining plugins and **installing all Mylyn plugins again** (which is okay, as your settings remain the same).

@Francis: And that was not caused by missing update sites. I think the underlying issue is more that most Mylyn connectors use a very narrow version range for their "host" plugins and updating a "mixture" of different Mylyn connectors then can get P2 into believing that the update cannot be done, although just updating *all* to the latest version is a valid solution. Not sure whether to blame Mylyn or P2 then...